# Reusing Popup window with differents UserControls

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls, popupwindow

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app.

I want to show differents user control with an unique PopUp window.

When I close a popup I immediately open the same pop up with another user control as child. I'm doing it like this:

```
popUpWindow.IsOpen = false;
popUpWindow.Child = null;

popUpWindow.Child = new UserControl2();
popUpWindow.IsOpen = true;
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Looks OK at first glance. What issue are you having?

Comment: I don't have any issue. I'm don't so much about Windows Phone programming, so I was not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to do it. You could also use `popUpWindow.ClearValue(Popup.ChildProperty);` to remove all the children, which makes it a bit more explicit and readable.